# Justifying that $\hat{H}^2\psi=\hat{H}(\hat{\psi})$, where $\hat{H}$ is a hamiltoniam operator

Tags: proof-verification, partial-derivative, quantum-mechanics

I'm going through Griffith's *Introduction to Quantum Mechanics*. The author defines the hamiltonian operator the following way:
$$ \hat{H}=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+V(x)$$
and then claims that:

$$ \hat{H}^2E=\hat{H}(\hat{H}E)$$

without specifying any proof.

I was thinking about ,,proving'' it (actually, obtaining an *intuitive* explanation of why this *might* be true) this way:

$$ \hat{H}(\hat{H})=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\left[-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+V(x)\right]+V(x)\left[-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+V(x)\right]$$

$$ \hat{H}(\hat{H})=\left(-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\right)^2-V(x)\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}-V(x)\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+V^2(x)$$

$$ \hat{H}(\hat{H})=\left(-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\right)^2-2V(x)\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+V^2(x)$$

$$ \hat{H}(\hat{H})=\left(-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+V(x)\right)^2=\hat{H}^2$$

But this is not a correct proof! For example, we cannot write $$ \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\cdot \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}=\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\right)^2$$
as they're not *numbers*, they're *operators*, each acting on another!

What's the proper method for proving such statement? (or - what can be done to make mine more rigorous?)

Meybe it's a silly question, but the problem with Griffith's book is that it in many places completely skips explanations and proofs, and this result is certainly not so trivial.

Comment: What is $E$? $i\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$?

Comment: E is a constant.

Comment: Multiplication of linear operators are defined as function composition, so $(\hat{H}^2)\psi = \hat{H}(\hat{H}\psi)$ is no more complicated than the identity $(f \circ g)(x) = f(g(x))$ (except for the delicate issue of whether $\hat{H}\psi$ actually lies in the domain of $\hat{H}$ again or not).

Answer (score 4):

Be careful when you square an operator, they would not commute:
$$\hat{H}^2\cdot = \left[-c(\partial_x)^2+V\right]^2\cdot=c^2(\partial_x)^4\cdot-c(\partial_x)^2(V\cdot)-cV(\partial_x)^2\cdot+V^2\cdot=\hat{H}(\hat{H}\cdot)$$

Whenever you want a proof involving an operator, write this operator acting on sth., for example I used the symbol $(\cdot)$

Comment: What do you mean by "they would not commute"? Could point this in my "proof"?

Comment: Yes, compare my expression to your second equation in which you write $\hat{H}(\hat{H})$. I mean, you asserted that $V\partial_x^2=\partial_x^2V$ which is false.

Comment: @VanDerWarden, As explicitly mentioned by HBR, you are dealing with operators, which means that $V$ is not simply a function but a multiplicative operator $\psi \mapsto V\psi$ which acts on states. So you will end up with a seemingly strange relation $$ \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}V - V\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} = 2V'\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + V'', $$ which is in fact a disguise of the following obvious identity $$ \frac{\partial^2(V\psi)}{\partial x^2} - V\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial x^2} = 2V'\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x} + V'' \psi. $$

Answer (score 1):

You said $E$ is a constant. So you are just trying to prove
$$\hat{H}^2=\hat{H}\hat{H}$$
But that's the definition!
$\hat{H}^2$ is the shorthand for $\hat{H}\hat{H}$

Comment: But, for example $\sin(x)\cdot \sin(x)=\sin^2 x\neq \sin(\sin{x})$, and in Griffiths we have $\hat{H}(\hat{H}\psi)...$

Comment: So your question is why $(\hat{H}^2)\psi=\hat{H}(\hat{H}\psi)$?

Comment: Anyway, it is well known that compositions of linear transformations, or matrix multiplications, are associative.

Comment: I am fairly certain that Griffiths is not using these parentheses to imply functional dependence, but just to show that the outer operator acts on the output of the action of the innermost operator on the wave function.